# Can I use a different port in Azure Container instances for public access?

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I'm using Azure Container instances.
I've created a container with the 5000 port exposed. To create a container, I used:
`az container create ... --ports 5000`  and I exposed port 5000 in my docker file.

I checked the logs, and it showed me:

```
"Not listening on: http:/[::]5000"
```

But when I tried to access it from the internet via domain or IP address, I got only a standard error:
HTTP ERROR 404.

I have no firewall.

Does Azure support this use case?
Thanks.

Comment: If the requirement is to just have the Azure Container Instances public access then you can follow this workaround- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1343527/azure-container-instances-and-public-access

Comment: I'm sorry, no. I tried a few things without success, so I switched to the 80/443 port.

Comment: You're deploying it from some custom image right? Can you show the code once or  confirm if your application is configured to listen on 0.0.0.0:5000. This configuration should allow it to be accessible from outside the container.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I decided to abandon this approach; it was just an experiment. But thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: The questions you answer tend to be about MS Azure configuration, pricing, infrastructure, and other cloud-related issues, instead of being practical programming problems. StackOverflow is meant to discuss only programming questions. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
for more details. Please post your non-programming question on other platforms such as [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/)
, and [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/tags/133/azure)
for immediate help. Thanks!